# PHP - button to change language using ajax

Tags: javascript, php

i need a simple php code that will change a variable after clicking on button that show languages here how

Change language

on click show languages

english value= en
frensh value= fr

if i click a english it set $language=en

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "give me teh codez" kind of site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it by using ajax/JQuery.Some thing like this

```
 $.ajax({
         async: false,
         url: 'getlangg.php',
         success: function(data) {
         last_id=data;

                      }
        });
```

And use  php code something like this

```
SELECT langg FROM yourtable
echo $langg;
```